# Connect render db to pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to connect my db from render to pgAdmin, but it always give me this timeout
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oEzm.jpg)

I tried [this](https://community.render.com/t/connecting-to-pgadmin/2024) guide and [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-create-and-connect-to-a-postgresql-database-with-render-and-pgadmin-577b326fd19d) other guide, but I got the same result

Comment: pgAdmin4 is not a database.  It is client.  You don't connect to it.

Comment: @jjanes who's saying that? my db is on render

Comment: You are:  "from render to pgAdmin"

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix the issue and successfully connect my pgAdmin to my database, which is hosted by Render. (This statement is different than
or opposite of your statement "connecting my db from render to pgAdmin").

Anyway, the issue seems to be 'Host name/address' under Connection tab in PgAdmin. Go to Render.com -> Dashboard -> Choose your Postgres database -> Info -> Scroll down to External Database URL (Ignore Hostname).

External Database URL should be something like this

> postgres://something_postgres_user:SOME_RANDOM_PASSWORD@SOMEHOSTNAME.oregon-postgres.render.com/something_postgres

Now, copy only the following portion and paste it to 'Host name/address' under Connection tab in PgAdmin:

> postgres://something_postgres_user:SOME_RANDOM_PASSWORD@**SOMEHOSTNAME.oregon-postgres.render.com**/something_postgres

Comment: worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used render DB before, but I will suggest you check if your render DB instance is created as public, or allows external connection.

Comment: Yes, they gave me an external connection url

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

From the full External Database URL:
postgres://your_postgres_user:your_password@your_host_name.your_region-postgres.render.com/your_db_name

Grab this portion: postgres://@your_host_name.your_region-postgres.render.com

and put into the "Host name/address" field

Fill out "Maintenance database" with your database name

Fill out "Username" with username

Answer (score 0):

**July 2023**
Error : unable to connec to server : connection failed : SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly (this will get solved with this solution)

**This is best solution for connecting pgaadmin4 to render database**

From Render.com get your external_database_url
eg : postgres://your_postgres_user:your_password@**your_host_name.your_region-postgres.render.com**/your_db_name

Host name / address : Use certain part of the external database url
eg : **your_host_name.your_region-postgres.render.com**

Maintainence database : Database name on render

Username : Username from render

Password : Password from render

Comment: For me the part that works is:

`your_host_name.your_region-postgres.render.com`

From the external URL: 

`postgres://your_postgres_user:your_password@your_host_name.your_region-postgres.render.com/your_db_name`